# Why does the Vs node always oscillate around the second harmonic in a VCO tail filter?

Tags: rf, analog, oscillator, design, passive-networks

Why does the Vs node always oscillate in the second harmonic even if we detune the Cf, Lf tail filter?

Is Acos(2wot) always valid for Vs?

How is it explained?

[image: schematic]

Comment: I suggest that you draw the shape of the drain \$I_{D,M1}\$ and \$I_{D,M2}\$ currents of M1 and M2 in one plot. Now sum these currents (\$I_{D,M1} + I_{D,M2}\$) to get the "tail current" that flows net marked \$V_S\$. What is the repitition rate of this current?

Comment: Another hint: This is similar to what happens in a bridge rectifier, a 50 Hz sinewave is rectified, however the ripple on the output voltage has a frequency of .... Hz? See: https://www.elprocus.com/full-wave-rectifier-circuit-working-theory/

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense as we can see that the frequency is twice times the fundamental.Thank you

Comment: Now you can write that as an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest that you draw the shape of the drain ID,M1 and ID,M2
> currents of M1 and M2 in one plot. Now sum these currents
> (ID,M1+ID,M2) to get the "tail current" that flows net marked VS. What
> is the repitition rate of this current?
> Another hint: This is similar to what happens in a bridge rectifier, a
> 50 Hz sinewave is rectified, however the ripple on the output voltage
> has a frequency of .... Hz? See:
> elprocus.com/full-wave-rectifier-circuit-working-theory – Bimpelrekkie

Yes, now it makes sense as we can see that the frequency is twice times the fundamental